# Adding a Dict item to a list and appending values having same key to a newer list item

Tags: python, dictionary, collections

I have the following implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict

prod = [
    [1, 'tomato', 'veg', 'Jan-1'],
    [1, 'banana', 'fruit', 'Jan-3'],
    [2, 'melon', 'fruit', 'Jan-2'],
    [3, 'apple', 'fruit', 'Jan-4'],
    [2, 'cucumber', 'veg', 'Jan-1']
]

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in range (0, len(prod)):
    f_name = prod[i][1]
    f_type = prod[i][2]
    f_date = prod[i][3]

    key = prod[i][0]

    d[key].append([f_name, f_type, f_date])

e = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
print ("***************")
print (e)

table_for_graph = []

for key, value in e.iteritems():
    table_for_graph.append(value)

print (table_for_graph)
```

The output I get is like this:

```
[[['tomato', 'veg', 'Jan-1'], ['banana', 'fruit', 'Jan-3']], [['melon', 'fruit', 'Jan-2'], ['cucumber', 'veg', 'Jan-1']], [['apple', 'fruit', 'Jan-4']]]
```

I want to create a list like this:

```
[
    ['tomato''\n''banana','veg''\n''fruit','Jan-1''\n''Jan-3'],
    ['melon''\n''cucumber','fruit''\n''veg','Jan-2''\n''Jan-1'],
    ['apple','fruit','Jan-4']
]
```

Meaning, I want to concatenate the items which have the same key.
How do I go about this? I am not familiar with iterating thorugh dict yet.

Comment: If you are not familiar with iterating through a dict, how did you get the code in the first place?

Comment: Can you please check your output? It's inconsistent in terms of separators.

Comment: Also, please add a plain Python tag

Comment: Thanks Mad Physicist! I am trying to learn, through coding :)

Comment: `range (0, len(prod))` == `range(len(prod))` and you might rather do `for el in prod` or even better rename `for product in products`

Comment: Also: `'tomato''\n''banana'` == `'tomato\nbanana'`

Comment: I am sorry I missed that. I did an upvote, but not check mark. I did that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, the loop that constructs the dictionary can be greatly simplified since the unpacking and repacking is superfluous unless you need to reorder the elements:

```
for item in prod:
    d[item[0]] = item[1:]
```

Second, `table_graph` does not require a loop at all initially:

```
table_for_graph = e.values()
```

Each item here is a nested list, like:

```
>>> e[1]
[['tomato', 'veg', 'Jan-1'],
 ['banana', 'fruit', 'Jan-3']]
```

You can effectively transpose it by zipping the bits together:

```
>>> zip(*e[1])
[['tomato', 'banana'],
 ['veg', 'fruit'],
 ['Jan-1', 'Jan-3']]
```

Putting it all together:

```
 >>> [s in line for line in zip(*e[1]) for s in line]
 ['tomato', 'banana', 'veg', 'fruit', 'Jan-1', 'Jan-3']
```

You can run that expression on every element of the dictionary:

```
table_for_graph = [[s for line in zip(*value) for s in line] for value in e.itervalues()]
```

Comment: Hello MadPhysicist, The output is not what I expected. The output is pasted below:[[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]]

Comment: @DeepakV. Fixed typo. Thx for the catch.